# Scaling a polygon such that each point gets displaced according to how far away that point is from the polygon's centroid

Tags: geometry, polygons, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

Basically, I want to scale a polygon $\mathcal{P}$, with $n$ vertices, such that each point $p\in\mathcal{P}$ gets displaced according to how far away that point is from the centroid $c\in\mathcal{P}$.

For this, I should be able to focus on just the boundary of this polygon $B=\partial\mathcal{P}$. So, my thought is that I should then be able to take each vertices $v_n$, note the distance $d_n\triangleq\Vert v_n,c\Vert$, and then radially displace each vertex according to a prescribed function $\rho\left( d_n\right)$.

Is this the way to go?

Now, if I was to use conic curves to describe this shape, how would I go about scaling something like that? I would imagine I would need to "scale" (or offset) each conic curve, but I do not know how something like that would be done.

If there is any work relating to this please let me know, ideally I would like to find some kind of computational geometry algorithm to implement something like this.

EDIT: I now realize that I simply cannot just displace each vertex as the edges will not displace uniformly, so I believe the answer is going to relate to conic curves. Thoughts?

EDIT: This is how I imagine a "scaling" would take place for, let's say a function similar to $\rho\left( d_n\right)\simeq\exp(d_n)$. See image here:

[image: Imagined non-unifirm scaling of polygon edge]

I know this isn't exact, but the image should make the point clear.

EDIT: It may be worth working in radial coordinates where conics are converted from rectangular to polar.

Comment: In vector notation the centroid of vertices $P_k$ is $G=\frac{1}{n}\sum P_k$. Let $\lambda$ be the scaling ratio, then each vertex would move to $P_k^{'} = G + \lambda (P_k - G) = \lambda P_k + (1-\lambda) G$.

Comment: @dxiv But what about for the points along the edges? These would scale differently, as the distance of these points will vary.

Comment: Every point on an edge is a linear combination of the vertices at its endpoints, so they all scale by the exact same ratio. Draw it on paper and look for similar triangles, or lookup [homothety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothety).

Comment: @dxiv Even if the points scale as a function of their distance from the the centroid? Even though the points along the edge are a linear combination of the vertices, the distance varies along that edge. Therefore, their displacement will also vary.

Comment: Of course their displacements will vary, but they will vary proportionally to the distance to the centroid, which is precisely what you asked for. All lines, angles, and proportions between segments will stay the same as in the original.

Comment: @dxiv 
I hope we are on the same page but I think I may have failed in explaining my problem, so I will make it more clear and if we are on the same page then I am just confused lol. So this is how I imagine a non-uniform scaling would take place for, let's say a function similar to ρ(dn)≃exp(dn) (see image in edited post above). Here the points along the edge vary in distance so their radial displacement also varies creating this curve.

Comment: Maybe something related to anisotropic scaling (found reading about Homothety)?

Comment: The image describes it better than the words before. The answer is similar, except $\lambda$ is no longer a constant, but rather a function of the distance to the centroid, so $P_k^{'} = G + \lambda\left(\left|P_k-G\right|\right) \cdot (P_k - G)$

Comment: @dxiv That is what I figured, so given that, the linearity of the edges will not be preserved, still leaving a computational problem to be solved involving, hopefully, just conic curves. I will play with this more as I think there is a path forward working in polar coordinates. If you have any suggestions let me know, but I think I will just make a new post depending on where this line of thought leads. Thanks! NOTE: I will be using these results in a computational geometry setting.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and write the complete problem there, including what you know and what you are trying to get. For arbitrary points and an arbitrary scaling function you can't (hope to) do any better than calculating each point individually. However, if you know the original shape and/or the scaling function then there may exist some shortcuts. But no one can guess unless you post all details.

Comment: Sounds good, I will do that tomorrow morning. But for now, both the function and initial state of the polygon are known.

Answer (score 1):

Taking center of gravity G as the center of similitude the scaling is just ***zooming in or zooming out***.

Erect a perpendicular through G and draw the polyhedron and polygons to verify that  all sides and their increments are in the same proportion. This is homothety with respect to G (c).. similar figures similarly placed so that parallel lines at any chosen sub-interval.

It is not clear to me why the sub-interval vector should trace some curve instead of a straight line as given. If any non-linearity is to be built in, should n't that non-uniform scaling rule at least be specified?

[image]

As you asked in ellipse dilation with respect to an arbitrary point the polygonal sides dilate to lines and ellipses to ellipses but not polygon side straight line to any ellipse.

[image]

Comment: That would only work for uniform scaling, correct?

Comment: Each point along the edge gets displaced according to a function $\rho$ which is dependent on the distance that point is from the centroid. For example, a point that is further away from the centroid will displace a larger amount than one that is closer to the centroid. As dxiv was saying about homothety but the $\lambda$ is not constant but a function of the measured distance. I am going to edit this post shortly to make it more clear what I am thinking about.